# Bootstrap grid aligning inaccurately and won't respond to .css file

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I am following along with the exercises in the Jump Start Bootstrap (DOWNLOAD LINK https://learn.vccs.edu/courses/406438/files/108188236/preview )

In chapter 02, we are creating a grid system. I have entered the code for the index.html and style.css files to format the grid as shown in the book.

The columns in the grid need to align vertically and horizontally, however, they simply align vertically only. The column divs also do not respond to the style.css file that is supposed to format them in size and color.

| **Bootstrap grid example screenshot** | **Bootstrap grid that my code outputs screenshot** |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

I have checked my code several times and compared it to the code in the book (which I added a download link above [Chapter 02 index.html file]) and I cannot find anything wrong with it.

This here is the code that I am using for the html and css files:
https://pastebin.com/MQWnJXvT

If anyone can take a look and give any suggestions or just managed to spot and point out a mistake that I missed, I would greatly appreciate it. I am scratching my head with this one and will probably continue to do the rest of the night.

The only issues I can think of is that I am assigning the wrong classes in the column divs or am placing the `<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">` line in the wrong section.

I thank everyone in advance who has any advice or suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working fine. The problem should be the link tag, set the path correctly.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    .col1 {
      background: #5C7080;
    }
    
    .col2 {
      background: #6BC0FF;
    }
    
    .col3 {
      background: #E8AA4C;
    }
    
    .col4 {
      background: #FF384E;
    }
  </style>

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col1">
        <h4>Column 1</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col2">
        <h4>Column 2</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col3">
        <h4>Column 3</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col4">
        <h4>Column 4</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```